# $f(x) = x \tan^{-1}(x\ln(x))$ find $f'(e)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$f(x) = x \tan^{-1}(x\ln(x))$ find $f'(e)$

my work

$f'(x)=\tan^{-1}(x\ln(x)) *1 + x$ ---> stack here

I know $\tan^{-1}(x)'=  \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

so $\tan^{-1}(x\ln(x)) = ???$

I need help to solve that question please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)=(x\times\arctan (x\ln(x)))'&=1\times \arctan (x\ln(x))+x \times\frac{(x\ln(x))'}{1+(x\ln(x))^2}\\\\
&=\arctan (x\ln(x))+x \times\frac{\ln(x)+1}{1+(x\ln(x))^2}
\end{align}
$$ then
$$
f'(e)=\arctan (e)+\frac{2e}{1+e^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x\tan^{-1}(x\ln(x))\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{x(\ln(x)+1)}{x^2\ln^2(x)+1}+\tan^{-1}(x\ln(x))\Longrightarrow$$

$$f'(e)=\frac{2e}{1+e^2}+\tan^{-1}(e)$$

Comment: tan−1(3) where you got 3 ???

Comment: sorry, it has to be $e$, I've changed it already

Comment: okay thank  you !!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

i don't know differentiating implicitly helps but i am going to try.  we have $$y = x\tan^{-1}\left(x \ln x\right) \to \tan(y/x) = x \ln x $$ differencing this give you $$\left(1+ \tan^2(y/x)\right)\left(\frac{dy}x - \frac{ydx}{x^2}\right) = dx + \ln x \, dx \tag 1$$ subbing $x = e, y = e\tan^{-1}(e), \tan(y/x) = e,$  we get 
$$\left(1+ e^2\right)\left(\frac{dy}e - \frac{e\tan^{-1}(e)dx}{e^2}\right) = 2dx  \to \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2e+(1+e^2)\tan^{-1}(e)}{1+e^2}$$